# Name a range in dynamically created excel sheet using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, range

I want to name a range in an excel sheet that is created dynamically. I tried following but it is not working.

```
With oWB
  For intCount = 1 To wbnum1
    .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(intCount + 1)) 
    .Sheets(intCount + 1).Name = "Sheet" & intCount.ToString()
    .Sheets(intCount + 1).Cells(19, 2).value = "Sheet" & intCount.ToString
    .Sheets(intCount+1).Range("A1:Z1")
    .Range.Name = "Numbers"
  Next
```

what is wrong with this?

Thanks

Comment: Try:  `.Sheets(intCount+1).Range("A1:Z1").Name = "Numbers"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't specifying a Range.

Presumably, you should merge your last and second to last line:

```
.Sheets(intCount+1).Range("A1:Z1").Name = "Numbers"
```

However, from experimentation it appears that assigning the name this way creates workbook level names resulting in only the last assignment being valid after you loop through your worksheets.

An alternate/safer way to do this is to add the name as a worksheet specific name via the worksheet's names collection:

```
.Sheets(intCount+1).Names.Add "Numbers", .Sheets(intCount+1).Range("A1:Z1")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim uniqueName as String = "A_NamedRangeName_" & i
Dim rnArea as Range = .ActiveSheet.Range(leftCol & startRow, rightCol & endRow)
Name name = .ActiveBook.Names.Add(uniqueName, rnArea)
```

Name Range names cannot:
- start with digits
- include , : ; characters
- be duplicate names, each must have a unique name
- be a reserved excel function name